# php: php error in ajax script not firing?

Tags: php, ajax, exception

i'm using post to send data to the server - the problem is if there's a php error in the script, the ajax handler won't report back that an error occured with that request.
any ideas how to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the PHP return an error to let the AJAX know something went wrong, or use a timeout or something on the AJAX side of things.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

jQuery has some features to do this too, iirc.

Also: accept some more questions as answered.

Comment: thanks - since stackexchange introduced that strange "you can set this an answer in .. minutes" i keep forgetting doing that .. :/